# How to run map reduce from the webpage

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am a beginner in hadoop, working on cloudera.
I have written the mapper and reducer code in python.

Now I wanted to make a page having a button which on click runs the map reduce program and displays the output.
How should I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime

list_of_format=['css','js','png','swf','aspx','jpeg','jpg','gif','ico']
def format(line):
    for check in list_of_format :
       if (line.decode('utf-8').lower()).find(check)!=-1:
           return False
    return True
for line in sys.stdin:

if format(line):
   data = re.findall('"([^"]*)"',line)
   ip=line[:line.find(" ")]
   i=line.find("[")
   j=line.find(" ",i)
   st=line[i+1:j]
   st=datetime.strptime(st,'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
   stry=data[0]
   try:
      hindex=stry.index(' HTTP')
   except:
      pass      
   qindex=stry.find('?')
   if qindex!=-1:
     k=len(stry)
     stry=''.join((stry[:qindex],stry[hindex:k]))
   print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(ip,st,stry )
```

above is my mapper code.similarly I have written reducer code.
Then i run hs mapper.py reducer.py inputfile outfile

Comment: Can you show some codes you tried ?

Comment: Hey. When I run my code through terminal (hs mapper.py reducer.py input file outfile) then it is working.What I want is to make a page having  a button and after clicking the button i should able to run the above command